# constructor calling the base class with braces

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I am trying to compile this piece of code:

```
 Server(uint16_t port, NetworkManager nmanager)
: TCPServer(port, nmanager){} : TCPServer(port, nmanager)
```

but I don't understand why two constructor calls for base class. Can someone please explain this line of code?
It also gives compile time errors as follow

```
/build/libs/network/tests/network/tcp_client_sersver_stress_tests.cpp:49:47: error: 
  use of undeclared identifier 'port'
: TCPServer(port, nmanager){} : TCPServer(port, nmanager)
/build/libs/network/tests/network/tcp_client_sersver_stress_tests.cpp:49:53: error: 
  use of undeclared identifier 'nmanager'
: TCPServer(port, nmanager){} : TCPServer(port, nmanager)
/build/libs/network/tests/network/tcp_client_sersver_stress_tests.cpp:49:35: error: 
  C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
: TCPServer(port, nmanager){} : TCPServer(port, nmanager)
/build/libs/network/tests/network/tcp_client_sersver_stress_tests.cpp:49:47: error: 
  'port_' is a private member of 'network::TCPServer'
: TCPServer(port, nmanager){} : TCPServer(port, nmanager)
/build/libs/network/include/network/tcp/tcp_server.hpp:94:45: note: declared private here uint16_t port_;
/build/libs/network/tests/network/tcp_client_sersver_stress_tests.cpp:49:53: error: 
  'manager_' is a private member of 'network::TCPServer'
: TCPServer(port, nmanager){} : TCPServer(port, nmanager)
/build/libs/network/include/network/tcp/tcp_server.hpp:99:45: note: declared private here std::shared_ptr<ClientManager> manager_;
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code cannot be compiled, because it's not valid C++. When defining a constructor, there can be *one* sequence of member initializers (including base class constructor calls). The snippet is more likely to be correct when you change it to

```
 Server(uint16_t port, NetworkManager nmanager)
    : TCPServer(port, nmanager)
 // ^ From here, initialize base class and data members ONCE, separated by ","
 //   No additional ":" is allowed
 {}
```